# Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] when trying to make migration in mysql docker container from local machine (Phpmig + Eloquent ORM)

Tags: php, docker-compose, eloquent, mysql-connector

I'm running a mysql docker container where I'd like to make migrations with phpmig using the Eloquent ORM without laravel. Unfortunately, when I try to make a migration I get the error

```
In Connection.php line 712:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from inform  
  ation_schema.tables where table_schema =  and table_name = migrations and t  
  able_type = 'BASE TABLE')     

In Connector.php line 70:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

My .env file:

```
# .env
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_HOST=application-mysql
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DATABASE=app_db
```

My config/autoload/database.global.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

$dotenv = new Dotenv();
$dotenv->load("." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '.env');
 
return [
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'username' => getenv('MYSQL_USER') ?: '',
        'password' => getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD') ?: '',
        'host' => getenv('MYSQL_HOST') ?: '',
        'database' => getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE') ?: '',
        'port' => getenv('MYSQL_PORT') ?: 3306,
        'charset' => getenv('MYSQL_CHARSET') ?: 'utf8',
        'collation' => getenv('MYSQL_COLLATION') ?: 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
];
```

phpmig.php

```
<?php

use Phpmig\Adapter;
use Pimple\Container;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$container = new Container();
$container['config'] = (include './config/autoload/database.global.php')["database"];
$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $capsule = new Capsule();
    $capsule->addConnection($c['config']);
    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();

   return $capsule;
};
$container['phpmig.adapter'] = function($c) {
    return new Adapter\Illuminate\Database($c['db'], 'migrations');
};
$container['phpmig.migrations_path'] = "." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'migrations';

return $container;
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  # PHP fpm
  application-backend:
    image: application-backend:latest
    restart: always
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/application
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/application
    container_name: application-backend

  # Nginx Service
  application-nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: application-nginx
    restart: always
    tty: true
    environment:
      - "APPLICATION_UPSTREAM=application-backend:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./docker/nginx/templates/:/etc/nginx/templates/
      - ./public/:/var/www/application/public/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  # MySQL Service
  application-mysql:
    image: library/mysql:8.0
    container_name: application-mysql
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - applicationMysqlData:/var/lib/mysql
      - applicationMysqlFiles:/var/lib/mysql-files

#Docker Volumes
volumes:
  applicationMysqlData:
    driver: local
  applicationMysqlFiles:
    driver: local
```

I was hoping to be able to make migrations with phpmig on my local machine as well as to interact with my database using the Eloquent ORM model, however, I can't even make the migration. I tried changing MYSQL_HOST in .env to the container's docker ip, tried changing MYSQL_PORT to 3307 as well as changing the structure and contents of phpmig.php file while deleting every image, container, volume and network and rebuilding them after every alteration, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

Try 'docker network ls', then 'docker network inspect {network name}'.
Maybe that will give you some insight and you can verify the db ip address.